# Rails Scope Not Working When Regular where() Query Does

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scopes

I am trying to build a relatively simple named scope in my `Products` class. Oddly, if I issue the query directly (a la `Product.where()`), I get the results I expect. However, if this query is changed to a `scope` declaration, the result set is `nil`.

Why does my query work when called directly but produce nothing when it is made into a scope? Here's the actual code:

```
scope :is_queued, where("status = 2 OR (status = 0 AND status_expires > ?)", DateTime.now )# <-- returns nil
Product.where("status = 2 OR (status = 0 AND status_expires > ?)", DateTime.now) # <-- returns 1+ results (as expected)
```

Thank you!

Tom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scopes defined with `scope` are evaluated once, when the `scope` is defined - so `DateTime.now` refers to when your app instance first started.

Try:

```
scope :is_queued, lambda { where("status = 2 OR (status = 0 AND status_expires > ?)", DateTime.now) }
```

Comment: Turned out to be a combination of this, plus a forgotten-about empty `is_queued` class method hanging out further down the file. Oops! :-) Thank you.